# cannot close top level window tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I'm writing a bit of code to sort out tools, and I have created a custom dialog box that the user will select a condition for the tool, however when I try and close the window it simply creates another blank top level window. what am I doing wrong?

```
def tool_condition_message(tool_ID):
    condition_win = Toplevel()
    condition_win.title('Condition')
    message = "What is the condition of " + tool_ID + " ?"
    Label(condition_win, text=message).pack()
    new = Button(condition_win, text='New', command=lambda:condition(4))
    new.pack(side=LEFT)
    good = Button(condition_win, text='Good', command=lambda:condition(3))
    good.pack(side=LEFT)
    fair = Button(condition_win, text='Fair', command=lambda:condition(2))
    fair.pack(side=LEFT)
    poor = Button(condition_win, text='Poor', command=lambda:condition(1))
    poor.pack(side=LEFT)

    return 0



def condition(value):
    global item_condition
    item_condition = value
    print(item_condition)
    destroy(Toplevel())
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62466172/edit) and make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `destroy(Toplevel())` is invalid because there is no `destroy()` function.  You should pass `condition_win` to `condition()` function and call `condition_win.destroy()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues with this piece of code - `destroy(TopLevel())`:

1. `destroy` is not a built-in python function so cannot be used in this way. The proper way is `{tkinter_widget}.destroy()`
2. `TopLevel()` is going to create a *new* top level widget (aka
   application window) so you won't be destroying one which already exists in any case. You need to destroy the instance of an existing window instead.

A couple changes are needed to get this to work:

```
# Pass the condition_win into the new condition function
new = Button(condition_win, text='New', command=lambda:condition(condition_win, 4))
good = Button(condition_win, text='Good', command=lambda:condition(condition_win, 3))
...

# Change condition to accept the existing window as well
def condition(condition_win, value):
    ...
    condition_win.destroy()
```